# Manage a Batch-based server in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I downloaded the binaries of a web server app. Extracting it leaves me with the following directory tree:

```
./
   bin/
      start.bat
      stop.bat
   lib/
      *.jar
      *.*
```

As a PowerShell fan, I would rather call `Start-MyWebServer.ps1` than `start.bat`.

This task would be simple if it wasn't for `start.bat`: it writes the logs directly in the console, and asks to *Press a key to continue...* before exiting (`pause`?). The same goes for `stop.bat`.

I've tried various solutions based on `Start-Process -FilePath "...\start.bat" -NoNewWindow`, with an without `-Wait` in order to start the server *in the background*...

I also tried using `Start-Job`:

```
Start-Job -Name "MyWebServer" -ScriptBlock {
   Start-Process -FilePath "...\start.bat" -Wait -NoNewWindow
} | Out-Null
```

This last solution **almost** works, i.e. when `Start-MyWebServer.ps1` returns, the server is still initializing, even though the job is marked as completed. Is there a better solution to my problem that polling the server until it's ready? Or is it the expected behavior of a `Start-*` commandlet?

---

Here is the content of `start.bat` (actually named `startup.bat`, credit: [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org)):

```
@echo off
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Startup Script for GeoServer
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

cls
echo Welcome to GeoServer!
echo.
set error=0

rem JAVA_HOME not defined
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto trySystemJava

rem JAVA_HOME defined incorrectly
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto badJava

rem Setup the java command and move on
set RUN_JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.

:checkGeoServerHome
rem GEOSERVER_HOME not defined
if "%GEOSERVER_HOME%" == "" goto noHome

rem GEOSERVER_HOME defined incorrectly
if not exist "%GEOSERVER_HOME%\bin\startup.bat" goto badHome

goto checkDataDir

:trySystemJava
for /f %%i in ('where java') do set RUN_JAVA=%%i
rem --- we might be on amd64 having only x86 jre installed ---
if "%RUN_JAVA%"=="" if DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) if NOT "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (
    rem --- restart the batch in x86 mode---
    echo Warning: No java interpreter found in path.
    echo Retry using Wow64 filesystem [32bit environment] redirection.
    %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c %0 %*
    exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
  )
if "RUN_JAVA%"=="" goto noJava
goto checkGeoServerHome

:noJava
  echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined, and no Java executable could be found.
goto JavaFail

:badJava
  echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
goto JavaFail

:JavaFail
  echo Please install Java or, if present but not in the path, set this environment variable via the following command:
  echo    set JAVA_HOME=[path to Java]
  echo Example:
  echo    set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8
  echo.
  set error=1
goto end

:noHome
  if exist ..\start.jar goto noHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined.
goto HomeFail

:badHome
  if exist ..\start.jar goto badHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
goto HomeFail

:HomeFail
  echo This environment variable is needed to run this program.
  echo.
  echo Set this environment variable via the following command:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_HOME=[path to GeoServer]
  echo Example:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_HOME=C:\Program Files\GeoServer
  echo.
  set error=1
goto end


:noHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined.
goto setHome

:badHomeOK
  echo The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
goto setHome

:setHome
  echo Temporarily setting GEOSERVER_HOME to the following directory:
  cd ..
  set GEOSERVER_HOME=%CD%
  echo %GEOSERVER_HOME%
  echo.
goto checkDataDir


:checkDataDir
  rem GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR not defined
  if "%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" == "" goto noDataDir
  goto setMarlinRenderer

:noDataDir
  rem if GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR is not defined then use GEOSERVER_HOME/data_dir/
  if exist "%GEOSERVER_HOME%\data_dir" goto setDataDir
  echo No valid GeoServer data directory could be located.
  echo Please set the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR environment variable.
  echo.
  echo Set this environment variable via the following command:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=[path to data_dir]
  echo Example:
  echo    set GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=C:\Program Files\GeoServer\data_dir
  echo.
  set error=1
goto end

:setDataDir
  set GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=%GEOSERVER_HOME%\data_dir
  echo The GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR environment variable is not defined correctly.
  echo Temporarily setting GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR to the following directory:
  echo %GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%
  echo.
goto setMarlinRenderer

:setMarlinRenderer
  cd %GEOSERVER_HOME%
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/s "%GEOSERVER_HOME%\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib\marlin*.jar"') do set MARLIN_JAR=%%i
  if "%MARLIN_JAR%" == "" (
    echo Marlin renderer jar not found
    goto run
  )
  set MARLIN_ENABLER=-Xbootclasspath/a:"%MARLIN_JAR%" -Dsun.java2d.renderer=org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine
  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %MARLIN_ENABLER%
goto run

:run
  cd %GEOSERVER_HOME%
  echo Please wait while loading GeoServer...
  echo.
  "%RUN_JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar
  cd bin
goto end


:end
  if %error% == 1 echo Startup of GeoServer was unsuccessful. 
  echo.
  pause
```

Comment: what is the content of start.bat?

Comment: `Get-Job` can be used to determine when the job ends. However, if the `start.bat` script contains a `PAUSE`, then I doubt it will end. Why would anyone name their program with the same name as an existing command?

Comment: @lit After a few seconds, the job has a `State` set to `Completed` (idk the difference with `Stopped`), however, the web server will not respond to HTTP requests before another few seconds. Two things shock me here: first, the job actually completes! Second, it does so before the server is actually operational.

Comment: @Odepax - @GuentherSchmitz asked for the content of `start.bat`. Are you able to edit the question and paste it in?

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz @lit `start.bat` would be a 150-line long file that checks for environment variables, asserts their values, calls `echo` a lot, and delegates the rest to Java and `start.jar`. None of this is my own code, apart from the PowerShell wrappers of course.

Comment: my suggestion is to remove "pause" at the very end of the file and run `& c:\path\to\startup.bat` in your powershell script

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the capturing of the output of the start.bat?

```
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.FileName = '...\start.bat'
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$psi.WindowStyle = 'Minimized'
$bytes = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$s = ''
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$done = 'Press any key to continue'
$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
for() {
  $i = $bytes.add($p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte())
  if( $bytes[$i] -lt 0 ) { break }
  $s = $enc.GetString($bytes)
  if( $s -match "`n${done}$" ) { break }
}
if( !$p.HasExited ) {
  $p.Kill()
  Write-Host 'done...'
}
$p.Dispose()
```